# mySql multiple time aggregates in query

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have managed to aggregate by time one value giving a query result like this:

```
SELECT date(takenat) AS takendate,
         hour(takenat) AS HourTaken, 
         avg(reading) AS ch1av 
FROM readings 
WHERE channelid = 4 
GROUP BY takendate, HourTaken 
ORDER BY takenat, HourTaken
```

Some sample output:

```
takendate HourTaken ch1av

2013-01-01 0 105.5082
2013-01-01 1 107.2167
2013-01-01 2 106.4833
2013-01-01 3 107.0333
```

However, I wish to have results (in the same query) for multiple channelid's

takedate HourTaken ch1av ch2av ch4av

So, for example hourly averages for channelid=1,2 and 4

I had a go with sub queries but my sql foo just aint enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound that you want something like this:

```
SELECT DATE(takenat) AS takendate,
       HOUR(takenat) AS HourTaken,
       AVG(CASE WHEN channelid = 1 THEN reading ELSE null END) AS ch1av, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN channelid = 2 THEN reading ELSE null END) AS ch2av, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN channelid = 4 THEN reading ELSE null END) AS ch4av
FROM readings 
WHERE channelid IN (1,2,4)
GROUP BY takendate, HourTaken
ORDER BY takenat, HourTaken
```

Answer (score 2):

use `IN` if you have multiple conditions,

```
select date(takenat) AS takendate,
       hour(takenat) AS HourTaken, 
       avg(reading) AS ch1av,
       channelid 
from   readings 
where  channelid IN (1,2,4)
group  by takendate, HourTaken, channelid 
order  by takenat, HourTaken
```

this is the same as using `OR`

```
select date(takenat) AS takendate,
       hour(takenat) AS HourTaken, 
       avg(reading) AS ch1av,
       channelid  
from   readings 
where  channelid = 1 OR 
       channelid = 2 OR
       channelid = 4
group  by takendate, HourTaken, channelid
order  by takenat, HourTaken
```